# Page transition in HTML/express

Tags: html, css, express

I have created web application using express. But my page rendering is not as smooth it look not good for this, I have an idea of page transition?

Is this way or any other way is there? I am new to this please guide me out(this site is looks like online ticket booking so there dynamic values in all pages)

Comment: You'd probably need Anuglar with a Routing service to achieve more 'dynamic' (fluid) experience. A node server will typically serve the pages to you just like any normal server would. Recommend you look up some tutorials/guides as Stackoverflow isn't the place for this :)

Comment: I am using express routing

Comment: Again.. express is a server side technology. You should be looking at client side unless the speed of page serving from the node server is slow.